# Symfony2: ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to [...]::__construct() must implement interface [...] none given

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4

The problem:

Any time I try to access the application I get this error:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   PL\OrderBundle\Entity\OrderHasComment::__construct() must implement
>   interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface,
>   none given, called in
>   /var/www/html/apps/portal_de_logistica/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Model/ModelManager.php
>   on line 416 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/apps/portal_de_logistica/src/PL/OrderBundle/Entity/OrderHasComment.php
>   line 48

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PL\OrderBundle\Entity\OrderHasComment`'s constructor asks for a mandatory argument but don't you provide it when you create a new instance of the object.

You're creating a new OrderHasComment (whatever that is) like this:

```
$object = new OrderHasComment() // <- missing argument
```

Remove that - it won't be needed anymore once your listener calls something like `setContext(...)` and it's not needed to create the object ... so it shouldn't be mandatory anyways.

```
// remove the mandatory argument or provide a default (i.e. $context = null)
public function __construct(ContextInterface $context) /
{
    // ...
```

... should become:

```
public function __construct()
{
```

This solves the issue that's responsible for the exception.

Comment: I fix the issues you tell me but now I get this error `ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> orderhascomment.listener -> security.context -> security.authentication.manager -> fos_user.user_manager -> fos_user.entity_manager".`

Comment: Also, can I do this to set the User? `public function onPrePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {

        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entity->setUser();
    }` or this is complety wrong?

Comment: The `onPrePersist` implementation looks okay but there's another problem that involves you injecting the `security.context` service. I can help you with that easily ... but ... my answer obviously **resolved this issue** (the exception-issue that was asked for in  this question). Please first upvote/accept the answer and ask a **new question** for your **new exception**. This is how stackoverflow works ... otherwise the page would be a huge mess where nobody would be able to find a solution to a concrete problem quickly :)

Comment: I leave you the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128402/is-secure-inject-the-whole-container-or-just-security-context